# drupal 7 ajax A to Z Buttons

Tags: ajax, drupal, button

I have a form in which there is combobox of job type. When i select the "Sales representative " from combobox a list of buttons from A to Z will appear by using AJAX like"

```
A B C D E F G ....... Z.
```

When we click on particular button for eg .if I click on `C` the `"Dealers"` Combobox will generate which has the values starting with `"C"` letter,if click `A` the combobox will load the values starting with `"A"` letter.
Next When we select the value of `dealer`  from combobox the next `"Dealer branch"` combobox  will generate and  load values of dealer branch related to that dealer.
Next when we select the value from `dealer` from `dealer branch` the next combobox of `"Sales Manager"` will generate and it load the values of sales manager related to that dealer branch.

I can't solve this problem can you plz help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the majority of the functionality you described using the [Hierarchical Select](https://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) Module. Read that page and it's documentation [here](https://drupal.org/node/262835). You may end up needing to create a custom module and use Forms API which is no easy feat and has a learning curve.

Forms api has a [states](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#states) functionality that makes AJAX much simpler. Read [this](https://drupal.org/node/1043838) for more info about the Forms API. Read [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&ved=0CHgQFjAJ&url=http://randyfay.com/states&ei=W5H9Uby2GdGt4AP2wIG4BA&usg=AFQjCNEpn-HUwI5CoCOwIEvTrPw60gWfAA&sig2=ttk_DOWwP21uGVTw5qU7nA&bvm=bv.50165853,d.dmg) for more info about states.